# Have Browser Notify You When a Site's SSL Certificate Changes

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome, ssl, openssl

I am having to set up a site with an additional need for security over what I would normally have for an SSL site. To handle this, I am establishing a private CA for the client. Once the import the CA I create as trusted, it will allow them to use the site without SSL errors popping up all the time.

The problem that I have, is that I need to setup the client's browser so that it will notify them if the server certificate changes (browsers won't do this, as long as the new certificate is from a trusted source.)

So, what I am wondering is if there is a browser out there, or a plugin for an existing browser that will allow this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) plugin for Firefox does this (it is active for all sites, not a specific one, but you could easily modify it to suit).